# Limit Coccinelle matches to expression of given type

Tags: coccinelle

A transform like the one below, works for `func_1(&something->field)` when something is a `foo_t` but does not catch cases where v is itself a field such as `func_1(&something->v->field)`

```
@@
typedef foo_t;
foo_t *v;
@@

- func_1(&v->field)
+ func_2(v)
```

On the other hand, if I use an expression like this:

```
@@
expression v;
@@

- func_1(&v->field)
+ func_2(v)
```

It works, but is too eager and may match cases where the type is not `foo_t`, just because some other type has the same field name.

Is there a way to get a match on expressions, but limit the expression type to be `foo_t`?